# LİNQ SQL Creating a New List Using Join VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql, ssms

I'd like to get **item_order** and **item_id** from ITEM_DEF and from ITEM_SYT **p4** colums. Also **item_id**s will be the same. And then sort it in a list order by Ascending.
So the new List will include 3 colums as **item_id**, **item_order** and **p4**.

EDIT: I just need to see how I should declare the List.

Here I have an example which performs well:

```
Dim ItemSytList As List(Of VLibrary.LINQ.ITEM_SYT) = New List(Of VLibrary.LINQ.ITEM_SYT)

ItemSytList = (From itemSyt As VLibrary.LINQ.ITEM_SYT In Context.ITEM_SYTs _
    Join itemDef As VLibrary.LINQ.ITEM_DEF In Context.ITEM_DEFs On itemSyt.item_id Equals itemDef.item_id _
    Where itemSyt.p1.ToUpper = "BDDK".ToUpper And itemSyt.p2.ToUpper = TableName.ToUpper _
    And itemDef.template_id = TemplateId And If(itemDef.item_close_date.HasValue, itemDef.item_close_date, StartDate) >= StartDate _
    And If(itemDef.item_open_date.HasValue, itemDef.item_open_date, EndDate) <= EndDate Select itemSyt).ToList
```

This code provides to keep ITEM_SYT's colums as it's children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is use an anonymous type. (Use implicit typing with LINQ whenever possible)

```
Dim ItemSytList =
    From itemSyt As VLibrary.LINQ.ITEM_SYT In context.ITEM_SYTs
    Join itemDef As VLibrary.LINQ.ITEM_DEF In context.ITEM_DEFs On itemSyt.item_id Equals itemDef.item_id
    Where itemSyt.p1.ToUpper = "BDDK".ToUpper And itemSyt.p2.ToUpper = TableName.ToUpper _
        And itemDef.template_id = TemplateId And If(itemDef.item_close_date.HasValue, itemDef.item_close_date, StartDate) >= StartDate _
        And If(itemDef.item_open_date.HasValue, itemDef.item_open_date, EndDate) <= EndDate
    Select New With {
        .item_order = itemDef.item_order,
        .item_id = itemDef.item_id,
        .p4 = itemSyt.p4}
```

You can access the results like this

```
Dim firstP4 = ItemSytList.OrderBy(Function(i) i.item_order).First().p4
```

Comment: Great answer! Thank you very much for your interest. 
I just changed these lines to order by ascending:

Select Data = New With {
                         .itemorder = itemDef.item_order,
                         .item_id = itemDef.item_id,
                         .p4 = itemSyt.p4
                         } Order By Data.itemorder